# Creating a server / service client

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have been developing an app that has to access a DB and return data has charts in a web page. since it is to be added to another software i had to create it as a local server / servce, using self host web api, returning the data as json so i can read it in my html file and create the charts.

The server / service works, but my problem remains on the client. I don't know if i have to create another project for my html or if i just add a folder with my html and all css and javascript.

Basically when i run it i have to display my html file.

I have been looking the web for examples / solutions but i can't seem to find one that will help me, i've checked:

- creating help pages with T4, but it includes all my css and js files in my html and when i want to change something i have to remove the include, debug and include it again;
- create a web app but when i run it it creates me 2 servers, the one i've created and the web page server, although my web page will access it using angularjs, i can't have the second server;

I'm a little lost on how i will do it.

Can someone give me some help?

I'm using VS2010, self-host WebApi, console app, entity framework, angularjs, nvd3 and d3.

thk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have developed your project using MVC4 you can create view/controller related to report in webapi project.Point add html files to this view.This won't create 2 servers.

Comment: i have started has mvc4, but since i convert it to a self host i had to make it as a console